# nmake modify macro based on target

Tags: macros, nmake, targets

I've got a Makefile.mak where I optionally create a test.exe or a DLL from my C-based source code. I'm using CL.EXE and NMAKE.

I'd like to modify my CFLAGS macro like this when the target is TEST.EXE:

```
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -DMAIN
```

And, of course, I use this in my C code:

```
#ifdef MAIN
... int main()... yada yada
#endif
```

I had tried

```
!IF $@ == "test.exe"
```

but it crashed out and doesn't work logically since the $@, target, isn't deterministic in that part of the makefile.

The logical place to define the additional macro is when defining the target but I don't see how to do that without NMAKE interpreting it as DOS command.

```
test.exe: test.obj
  CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -DMAIN
  $(LINKER) /out:$@ $(LIB) $*.obj $(LIBS)
```

It'd be easier with gmake, I know. I don't have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will present two solutions: one which does what you request, namely modifying `CFLAGS` based on the target, and a second one which may be a better approach.

Suppose you have a file `multiply.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int a, int b) {
   return a * b;
}

#ifdef MAIN
int main() {
   printf("Unit test: multiply(2, 3) = %d\n", multiply(2, 3));
}
#endif
```

which you would like to add to a static library `my_lib.lib`, and also use as a stand-alone unit test.

One standard way of adding `-DMAIN` to `CFLAGS` is to use NMAKE recursively. The second invocation of NMAKE could use a different makefile or, as as presented here, use the *same* makefile with a flag to prevent an infinite recursive loop.

```
TARGETS = my_lib.lib multiply.exe
CFLAGS  = -W4 -O2 -nologo -Zi

all: $(TARGETS)
my_lib.lib: multiply.obj

my_lib.lib:
    lib -nologo -out:$@ $**

!ifndef RECURSE
multiply.exe:
    nmake -nologo CFLAGS="-DMAIN $(CFLAGS)" RECURSE= $@
!endif

multiply.obj: .FORCE

.FORCE:
```

If `RECURSE` is defined, the built-in rule is used to create the test program `multiply.exe`.

This solution works. But it requires that `multiply.obj` be remade every time it is used, because there are two versions of it floating around: one with a `main` and one without.

The second solution distinguishes between these object files.

```
TARGETS = my_lib.lib multiply.exe
CFLAGS  = -W4 -O2 -nologo -Zi

all: $(TARGETS)
my_lib.lib: multiply.obj
multiply.exe: $*.TEST_obj

my_lib.lib:
    lib -nologo -out:$@ $**

multiply.exe:
    link -nologo -out:$@ $**

.c.TEST_obj:
    $(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -c $< -Fo$@
```

This gives:

```
>nmake -nologo
        cl -W4 -O2 -nologo -Zi /c multiply.c
multiply.c
        lib -nologo -out:my_lib.lib multiply.obj
        cl -DMAIN -W4 -O2 -nologo -Zi -c multiply.c -Fomultiply.TEST_obj
multiply.c
        link -nologo -out:multiply.exe multiply.TEST_obj
```

Trying to create a `.exe` file directly from the `.c` file, as in:

```
.c.exe:
    $(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) $<
```

does not work, because this still creates a `.obj` file which clobbers the other version.

**Edit:** `.SUFFIXES: .TEST_obj` does not seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my second answer.  It does not directly address the OP's question, but is much shorter and matches the title, and may help anyone arriving via search.

Suppose for example you have two files `aaa.c` and `bbb.c`, and you wish to use the MSVC switch `-fp:fast` when compiling the second.  With GNU `make`, you can solve this using the two-line Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall
bbb.o: CFLAGS += -ffast-math
```

which gives as desired:

```
make aaa.o bbb.o
cc -O3 -Wall   -c -o aaa.o aaa.c
cc -O3 -Wall -ffast-math   -c -o bbb.o bbb.c
```

For `nmake`, to achieve the same result you can use recursion.  The five-line Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -W3 -O2 -nologo -Zi
!ifndef HAVE_ADDED_FP_FAST
bbb.obj:
        @nmake -nologo HAVE_ADDED_FP_FAST= CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -fp:fast" $@
!endif
```

will give:

```
nmake -nologo aaa.obj bbb.obj
        cl -W3 -O2 -nologo -Zi /c aaa.c
aaa.c
        cl -W3 -O2 -nologo -Zi -fp:fast /c bbb.c
bbb.c
```

It might be clearer to put `HAVE_ADDED_FP_FAST=yes` in the recursive invocation.  Its purpose is to prevent an infinite loop.